# Android communicate with BLE via BluetoothGatt (read / send data problem)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm using BluetoothGatt to make communication for BLE device and Android device.
I have using the sample code to connect these two devices.
But I'm truly stuck on transmitting the data between these two devices.
[image]

[image]

And my code is as below.

```
public class DeviceControlActivity extends Activity {
    private final static String TAG = DeviceControlActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME = "DEVICE_NAME";
    public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "DEVICE_ADDRESS";

    private PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;

    private TextView mConnectionState;
    private TextView mDataField;
    private String mDeviceName;
    private String mDeviceAddress;
    private ExpandableListView mGattServicesList;
    private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>> mGattCharacteristics =
            new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();
    private boolean mConnected = false;
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mNotifyCharacteristic;

    private final String LIST_NAME = "NAME";
    private final String LIST_UUID = "UUID";

    private ServerApiService serverApiService;

    private GPSTracker gps;
    private String address;
    private String filename, outputFile;

    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic bluetoothGattCharacteristicHM_10;

    // Code to manage Service lifecycle.
    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
            mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
            if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
                finish();
            }
            // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
            mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mBluetoothLeService = null;
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d("Test", "action: " + action);
            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                preferenceHelper.setConnected(true);
                mConnected = true;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = false;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                clearUI();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
                displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                Log.d("Test", "extra: " + intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
                displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));

                final byte[] rxBytes = bluetoothGattCharacteristicHM_10.getValue();
                final byte[] insertSomething = {(byte) '\n'};
                byte[] txBytes = new byte[insertSomething.length + rxBytes.length];
                System.arraycopy(insertSomething, 0, txBytes, 0, insertSomething.length);
                System.arraycopy(rxBytes, 0, txBytes, insertSomething.length, rxBytes.length);

                if (bluetoothGattCharacteristicHM_10 != null) {
                    bluetoothGattCharacteristicHM_10.setValue(txBytes);
                    mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(bluetoothGattCharacteristicHM_10);
                    mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(bluetoothGattCharacteristicHM_10, true);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner =
            new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                            int childPosition, long id) {
                    if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
                        final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                                mGattCharacteristics.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
                        final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
                        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                            // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
                            // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
                            if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                        mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                                mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                            }
                            Log.d("Test", "read characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid());
                            if (characteristic.getUuid().equals("0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")) {
                                sendLongSMS();
                            }
                            mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                        }
                        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                            mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                    characteristic, true);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };

    private void clearUI() {
        mGattServicesList.setAdapter((SimpleExpandableListAdapter) null);
        mDataField.setText(R.string.no_data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gatt_services_characteristics);

        preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(this);

        serverApiService = ServiceGenerator.getInstance(this).create(ServerApiService.class);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        mDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME);
        mDeviceAddress = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        // Sets up UI references.
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.device_address)).setText(mDeviceAddress);
        mGattServicesList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.gatt_services_list);
        mGattServicesList.setOnChildClickListener(servicesListClickListner);
        mConnectionState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connection_state);
        mDataField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_value);

        getActionBar().setTitle(mDeviceName);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
        bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
        if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
            final boolean result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
            Log.d(TAG, "Connect request result=" + result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
//        unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
//        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
//        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_services, menu);
        if (mConnected) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_disconnect).setVisible(true);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_disconnect).setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_connect:
                mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_disconnect:
                mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void updateConnectionState(final int resourceId) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mConnectionState.setText(resourceId);
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayData(String data) {
        if (data != null) {
            mDataField.setText(data);
        }
    }

    private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
        if (gattServices == null) return;
        String uuid = null;
        String unknownServiceString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_service);
        String unknownCharaString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_characteristic);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData
                = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
        mGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();

        // Loops through available GATT Services.
        for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
            HashMap<String, String> currentServiceData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
            currentServiceData.put(LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
            currentServiceData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
//            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(currentServiceData, true);
            gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData =
                    new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics =
                    gattService.getCharacteristics();
            ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas =
                    new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

            // Loops through available Characteristics.
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
                charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
                HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                currentCharaData.put(LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownCharaString));
                currentCharaData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
                gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);

            }
            mGattCharacteristics.add(charas);
            gattCharacteristicData.add(gattCharacteristicGroupData);
        }

        SimpleExpandableListAdapter gattServiceAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                gattServiceData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
                new String[]{LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},
                gattCharacteristicData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
                new String[]{LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}
        );
        mGattServicesList.setAdapter(gattServiceAdapter);
    }

    private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        return intentFilter;
    }
}

public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";

    public final static UUID UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT =
            UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);

    // Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
    // connection change and services discovered.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {


        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicRead characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid());
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicChanged characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid());
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            byte[] data;
            byte b = 0x00;
            data = new byte[]{b};
//            BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(IMMEDIATE_ALERT_UUID);
//            if (service != null) {
//                characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(IMMEDIATE_ALERT_LEVEL_UUID);
//                characteristic.setValue(data);
//                gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
//            }
        }
    };

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        Log.d(TAG, "broadcastUpdate characteristic: action | " + action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                                 final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

        // This is special handling for the Heart Rate Measurement profile.  Data parsing is
        // carried out as per profile specifications:
        // http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml
        Log.d(TAG, "broadcastUpdate characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid());
        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
            int format = -1;
            if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
                Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
            } else {
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
                Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
            }
            final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));
        } else {
            // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
            final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            Log.d("Test ble", "byte: " + data);
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
                for(byte byteChar : data)
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
                Log.d("Test ble", new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
            }
        }

        Log.w(TAG, "broadcastUpdate()");

        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();

        Log.v(TAG, "data.length: " + data.length);

        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
            for(byte byteChar : data) {
                stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));

                Log.v(TAG, String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            }
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
        }

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public BluetoothLeService getService() {
            return BluetoothLeService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // After using a given device, you should make sure that BluetoothGatt.close() is called
        // such that resources are cleaned up properly.  In this particular example, close() is
        // invoked when the UI is disconnected from the Service.
        close();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * Initializes a reference to the local Bluetooth adapter.
     *
     * @return Return true if the initialization is successful.
     */
    public boolean initialize() {
        // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter through
        // BluetoothManager.
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the GATT server hosted on the Bluetooth LE device.
     *
     * @param address The device address of the destination device.
     *
     * @return Return true if the connection is initiated successfully. The connection result
     *         is reported asynchronously through the
     *         {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     *         callback.
     */
    public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The disconnection result
     * is reported asynchronously through the
     * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     * callback.
     */
    public void disconnect() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure resources are
     * released properly.
     */
    public void close() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }

    /**
     * Request a read on a given {@code BluetoothGattCharacteristic}. The read result is reported
     * asynchronously through the {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, int)}
     * callback.
     *
     * @param characteristic The characteristic to read from.
     */
    public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        Log.d(TAG, "readCharacteristic characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid());
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }

    /**
     * Enables or disables notification on a give characteristic.
     *
     * @param characteristic Characteristic to act on.
     * @param enabled If true, enable notification.  False otherwise.
     */
    public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                              boolean enabled) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);

        Log.d(TAG, "setCharacteristicNotification characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid());
        // This is specific to Heart Rate Measurement.
//        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
//            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
//                    UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
//            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
//            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
//        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of supported GATT services on the connected device. This should be
     * invoked only after {@code BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()} completes successfully.
     *
     * @return A {@code List} of supported services.
     */
    public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;

        return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
    }

    public void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
}
```

Where should I edit to make the data communication for the devices?

Comment: The 1800 and 1801 services are probably not what you are most interested in as they are generic Bluetooth services (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/). The fff0, fff1, and fff2 are custom services so it is difficult to know if they are read, write, or notify and what data is required. Maybe use a generic tool like nRF Connect to find out more about those custom services (https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an open source library that uses the Bluettoth LE to communicate with other devices (you can send both text and raw data), I link you the github page of the library:
https://github.com/niedev/BluetoothCommunicator

You can directly use the library or see the code to get an example of a working bluetooth le, there aren't many out there.

If you see that the code is too long don't worry, most of it is to improve the connection (reconnection in case of unintentional loss of a device signal, error checking, splitting and rebuilding of long messages, etc.) it is not essential to have a working bluetooth le.

I did some tests and it works better than nearby connections (only if the devices are not under the same wifi network) and wifi direct, the only flaw is that bluetooth has problems in case of more than 4/5 devices connected between them (maybe with a star topology you can increase the number) and that my library does not have message encryption, but you can always add it yourself, the code is open source :)